# Can a Cisco PIX Fiewall be used as a router?

Tags: cisco, router, firewall, pix

I have 2 [Cisco PIX 525 Firewalls](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/pix-525-security-appliance/product_data_sheet09186a0080091b09.html) and I don't have any *router*.

They are running version 7.2.

Can i use that as a Layer 3 router and use its interfaces for different subnets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the immortal words of Cisco (circa 1999), "*the PIX is a firewall, not a router*"

That said, it can be used as a router. But you're better off using *anything* else, as it's firewall nature is going to be a pain in the ass. (I used to do it with a PIX 520, and I hated it for all time.) If it's what you have, then it's all you have, but I cannot over emphasize how much better off you'll be with an actual *router*. (buy one, *build one*, whatever it takes.)

Comment: (build one == a PC, a box of NICs, and linux or freebsd)

Comment: Actually i have one router 2600 but it has only one ethernet inetrface. i need atleast two interfaces. or can we do with one interface. its just my small home lab. that firewall i got for 50 bucks :)

Comment: One interface, a couple of vlans and a managed switch?

Comment: @TomO'Connor yes